# Doctrine 1 paginator adapter for Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, pagination, doctrine-1.2

Where can I find paginator adapter class for Zend Framework 1 and Doctrine 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the one provide in this [page](https://gist.github.com/mdjaman/9bd3f764f05ab65122ca). An example of implementation can be found [here](http://ciaranmcnulty.com/Simplify-pagination-logic-using-a-custom-zend-paginator-adapter/)